# Windows svchost/NetworkService using all the bandwidth

Tags: windows, svchost

[image]

How can I stop it or at least reduce the bandwidth it uses?

Comment: That's possibly Win10 1804 rollout.

Comment: Set Network Connections as Metered, including Ethernet. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-ethernet-connection-metered-windows-10

Comment: @LotPings Is it possible somewhere to reduce the bandwidth windows uses for updates? Couldn't find it.
@ DrMoishePippik Problem is I don't want to set my whole connection as metered. I just want to prevent things from using the entire bandwidth by surprise with no possibility to pause it.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of task manager of that same PID showing all the services under that same PID svchost.exe?